# How to remove a a particular row value from a datatable based on a condition

Tags: c#

I have a  `DataTable` like this

```
name     age
------------
kumar    27
kiran    29
anu      24
peter    34
tom      26
manu     35
sachin   37
geetha   23
```

Now I have another `DataTable` like this with one column:

```
name
----
manu
tom
anu
```

I need to compare the value in the column **name** here and remove all the rows that share the same name. Now the result output should be like this:

```
name     age
------------
kumar    27
kiran    29
peter    34
sachin   37
geetha   23
```

How can I achive this result?

Comment: @prince23: I changed my solution. You should choose either Jerod's approach (good!) or my new approach (also good now, based on Jerod's).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean [.NET datatables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) and not SQL tables. One approach is the following. Convert your second datatable to a dictionary, something like this:

```
// create a lookup table to ease the process
Dictionary<string, string> dict = (from row in removeNames.AsEnumerable()
                                   select (string) row["name"])
                                  .ToDictionary(k => k);
```

You must loop from end to first, otherwise you get problems (cannot use `foreach` here, it'll throw an exception).

```
// loop top to bottom
for(var i = firstDT.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var row = firstDT.Rows[i];
    if(dict.Exists((string) row["name"]))
    {
        firstDT.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

---

### Edit: better solution

Partially inspired by a little discussion with Jerod below, I figured there had to be a way to do this with a LINQ expression that's easy to read and apply. Previously, it didn't work, because I enumerated the DataRowView itself, which, when you try to remove something, will raise an `InvalidOperationException`, telling you that the collection was modified. Here's what I did, and it works because we use `Select` to create a copy of the row items:

```
// TESTED, WORKS
// assuming table contains {name, age} and removeNames contains {name}

// selecting everything that must be removed
var toBeRemoved = from row in table.Select()
                  join remove in removeNames.AsEnumerable()
                    on row["name"] equals remove["name"]
                  select row;

// marking the rows as deleted, this will not raise an InvalidOperationException
foreach (var row in toBeRemoved)
    row.Delete();
```

Comment: your for-conditional seems to be wrong: use `for (var i = firstDT.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @Scoregraphic: after all those years, I still continue making the exact same mistake... lol. Fixed it, thanks. I also changed the code with the correct DataTable properties/methods, so now it should "just work" (I hope, warning: not tested).

Comment: @downvoters: please be so courteous to explain *why* you downvote. What is wrong with the solution?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is:

1. Create a expression to match the rows; i.e. "name='manu' OR name='tom' OR name='anu'"
2. Execute the expression against the original data table to select the rows to delete.
3. Loop through and delete all of the matching rows.

Assumptions:`table` = original data table, `table2` = filter data table.

```
string expression = string.Join( " OR ", table2.AsEnumerable().Select( 
     row => string.Format( "name='{0}'", row["name"] )).ToArray() );

foreach( DataRow row in table.Select( expression ) )
{
    row.Delete();
}
```

Comment: Note that using foreach + delete (remove rows), will invalidate the foreach-loop and has the effect of skipping over certain rows, or worse. Never use foreach when you need to add or remove items to the collection inside the loop.

Comment: @Abel. Delete in this case is not removing the row from the collection I'm enumerating. It will be marking the row as deleted in the data table. I believe it's still there if you look hard enough.

Comment: I've just gotten around in testing that assessment as I was a bit surprised (I don't use `DataTable` too often). Indeed, if you go through `DataTable.AsEnumerable()`, as I did, an `InvalidOperationException` will be thrown with *"Collection was modified"*. However, using `Select` does not have this problem. Why? Because it returns a new array of `DataRow` items. The `row.Delete()` still works, because each item points to the original `DataRow`. When you `Delete` it, it still exists, with `Rowstate.Detached`. In other words: a good solution and I learned something along the way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a simple query :
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.name IN (SELECT name FROM table2)

Comment: That assumes there's a backing SQL table, but that's not necessarily the case when using `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the table that you wish to remove from you could do something like this.

```
foreach(DataRow rowTable2 in dataSet.Tables["Table2"].Rows)
{
    foreach(DataRow rowTable1 in dataSet.Tables["Table1"].Rows)
    {
         if(rowTable1["NameColumn"].ToString() == rowTable2["NameColumn"].ToString())
         {
             dataSet.Tables["Table1"].Rows.Remove(rowTable1);
         }
    }
}
```

That is a very simple easy way to get what you need done.